# Testing a helpbook outside of an application

Tags: macos, cocoa, helper

I am creating a Help Book for my application. What would help a lot is if I could take the *.help bundle and load it into the help view directly for testing without using the application's Help menu option first.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no special way to do this other than to build and run your app, then request help. The only thing to test would be that the help index was created properly (by searching for keywords) anyway. The rest you can test in Safari. It'll look the same.